# save a file name with date format yyyy_mm_dd hh_mm_ss

Tags: c, datetime, opencv, raspberry-pi

i'm working on a project with Raspberry and opencv, i want to save a picture taken by the camera pi with the date system.
i'm programming with c and i used ctime but i don't get the format  yyyy_mm_dd hh_mm_ss, here is my code.`

```
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    printf("%s\n", ctime(&t));
    sprintf (nmphoto, "images/%d%s.jpg", sequence++,ctime(&t));
    cvSaveImage(nmphoto,userdata.image2,p);`
```

i would like to use this methode

```
  time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [80];
    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
    strftime (buffer,80,"Now it's %I:%M:%S.",timeinfo);
    puts (buffer);
```

but i don't know how to deal with the buffer and concat it with the sequence++ which is the id of the picture.
any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

try to use:

```
sprintf (nmphoto, "images/%d%s.jpg", sequence++, buffer);
```

It will place the string in `buffer` in place `%s`.

Comment: thanks, it works ! i also added option:strftime (buffer,80," %Y%B%a%I:%M:%S.",timeinfo);